# Intermittent/random `Can't connect to MySQL server on 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX' (60)`?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, server

A little background: I had to upgrade a service from PHP 5.6 to PHP 7.4. Database module was using old `mysql_*` functions, so the the first step was to replace them by `mysqli_*` and look for possible bugs, at the end it worked fine on local development environment.

As there weren't any visible bugs while testing phase, it was released to a test server. Then it started randomly an intermittently to log the following warning:

`(HY000/2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX' (60)`

If you check database server at that moment it replies OK, it is not down. Also there are other 3 servers online hosting the same service and they don't show the described problem meaning database server is online and running.

Also does the 60 surrounded by parentheses means something? I know it corresponds to MySQL's `Global Error Message` but error number 60 (EE_SSL_ERROR) wasn't added until version 8.0.13. Could it means the same in MySQL 5.6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digins and tests we (team) finally discovered it was related to client library connecting to older server.