# What's the meaning of the error code (60)?

Tags: php, mysql, database, connection, mysql-5.6

Given the following client error message:

> Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'server' (60)

What's the meaning of error code 60? MySQL v5.6 and v5.7 do not provide any info about it in docs, on the other hand v8.0 just says:

> Error number: 60; Symbol: EE_SSL_ERROR;
>
> Message: SSL error: %s.

It seems to be related to SSL, but the same applies to previous versions of MySQL?

**Update**:

The connection problem I was having was solved. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68965594/7771926

Anyway the meaning of *60* still an unknown to me

Comment: this error code means it can not establish a connection to mysql properly

Comment: I know what the error 2003 means, but the message number 60 is what I'm really asking, thinking it would help troubleshoot the error somehow. Worth mention that this is happen intermittently

Comment: you have to check you host its is not defined accurately.

Comment: I might add that this problems occurs intermittently and database server is being used by other sister sites, not sure if this will fix it, I have to try it though

Answer (score 0):

If database server is on a remote machine, then try to test the client-server connectivity using ping command, for instance:

ping server_ip_address

If you are able to ping, then try:

mysql -u username -p -h host_address -P port

If all the above commands run successfully, but you still see the error, open the mysql config file.

vi /etc/mysql/my.cnf

OR

vi /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf

Look for the line below and comment it out using the # character:

bind-address = 127.0.0.1

Save the file and exit, afterwards restart the mysql service like:

sudo systemctl start mysql.service
OR
sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld start

Comment: I've found this answer in the tons of similar questions, but this problems occurs intermittently and database server is being used by other sister sites, not sure if this will fix it, I have to try it though